# Extract data from certificate

Tags: rsa, public-key

I wrote application client-server. Now I would like to add safe connection.

**First**

When client connect to server - server send certificate in `*.crt` file.

Now I want to extract from this file the **public key** and validate certificate - check it is safe.

I use Lazarus/Delphi/Free Pascal

Can you tell me how can I extract from this file public key ready for use in hexadecimal (byte) format?

I know that in this file is $p$, $q$ and rest but I want final public key ready to use.

Maybe if not in my programming language then I can do this on my computer? Linxu, Windows?

How can I do this with private key? I have key in file with header:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: This seems to be more a question for Stack Overflow. See. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143606/how-to-save-public-key-from-a-certificate-in-pem-format

Comment: It would be reasonable to implement with openssl api as much functionality as possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to do this with openssl.

Say foo.crt is your crt file. Then,

```
$ openssl x509 -in foo.crt -text -noout
```

will print all the necessary information (issuer, pkey : modulus rsa and exponent, signature algorithm etc) in text format.

If you  give

```
$ openssl x509 -in foo.crt -text -noout > foo.txt
```

you will save the previous information to foo.txt file.

To answer your question

> Can you tell me how can I extract from this file public key ready for
>   use in hexadecimal (byte) format?

one way to do this is first export the public key and then convert it to  hex form

```
  $ openssl x509 -in foo.crt  -noout -pubkey > foo-public
  $ openssl rsa -noout -text  -in foo-public -pubin > foo-public-hex
```

Now foo-public-hex contains your pkey in hex format.

Then you wrote

> I know that in this file is p, q and rest but I want final public key
>   ready to use.

I am not sure I follow you...
the private key is not in the .crt file but in .key file and server wont sent it to the client.

If foo.key is you private key  then giving

```
$openssl rsa -noout -text  -in foo.key
```

you will see the private exponent and the primes p,q in hex form.

Comment: Nitpick: openssl commandline is available for and works the same on all Unixes and Windows, not just LInux. VMS is a little different, but not much.